# My callback function doesn't return "undefined" as I expect

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension and I  wrote this code.

I expect it prints 'Object {value: "set up"}' wnen I call options.getMode().
But, it prints 'undefined'.

```
var Options = function(){};

Options.prototype = {

    getMode: function(){

            chrome.storage.sync.get('value', function(e){         
               console.log(e); // it prints 'Object {value: "set up"}' in console.
               return e;
             })
    }
}


var options = new Options();

console.log(options.getMode()); // it prints "undefined" in console.
```

The second argument for chrome.storage.sync.get() is a callback function.
I wonder if a callback function doesn't return the object(e).

I want it to prints out 'undefined' when I call options.getMode().

What's wrong with this code?

Please help me out!

I think I'm misunderstanding something very basic.

Thanks!!

Comment: `return chrome.storage.sync.get(...);` should work, if `chrome.storage.sync.get()` returns a value synchronously

Comment: *"What's wrong with this code?"* You are not returning a value from `getMode`. Returning the value from the callback does not magically return it from `getMode`.

Comment: @LightStyle oh I see... if it runs synchoronously, callback returns a value. I got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 return chrome.storage.sync.get('value', function(e){         
      console.log(e); // it prints 'Object {value: "set up"}' in console.
      return e;
 });
```

**Full code**

```
var Options = function(){};
Options.prototype = {
    getMode: function(){
               return chrome.storage.sync.get('value', function(e){         
                 console.log(e);
                 return e;
               });
    }
}

var options = new Options();
console.log(options.getMode());
```

Comment: When console.log is called within the callback, it prints the object. But, when console.log is called at the end, it prints "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Storage.get is asynchronous.

So your code should look like this:

```
var Options = function(){};

Options.prototype = {

    getMode: function(callback){

            chrome.storage.sync.get('value', function(e){
               //this function is executed somewhere in the future        
               callback(e);
             })
    }
}


var options = new Options();
options.getMode(function(mode){
    //do some stuff with mode here   
    console.log("Mode is", mode);
});
```